# tensorflow object detection api GridAnchorGenerator is not consists with the faster rcnn paper

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

In grid_anchor_generator.py, the anchor generated by this code is not the same with Faster RCNN paper implementation. 
In Google Object Detection API, the anchor caculated in feature map position `[0, 0]` is :

```
[[ -83.50967407  -48.25482941   97.50967407   42.25482941]
 [-174.01934814  -93.50965881  188.01934814   87.50965881]
 [-355.03869629 -184.01931763  369.03869629  178.01931763]
 [ -57.00000763  -67.           71.00000763   60.99999619]
 [-121.00001526 -131.          135.00001526  124.99999237]
 [-249.00003052 -259.          263.00003052  252.99998474]
 [ -38.25483704  -93.50965881   52.25483704   87.50965881]
 [ -83.50967407 -184.01931763   97.50967407  178.01931763]
 [-174.01933289 -365.03866577  188.01933289  359.03866577]]
```

While in faster rcnn paper's author implementation, the anchors is :

```
   [[ -83.,  -39.,  100.,   56.],
    [-175.,  -87.,  192.,  104.],
    [-359., -183.,  376.,  200.],
    [ -55.,  -55.,   72.,   72.],
    [-119., -119.,  136.,  136.],
    [-247., -247.,  264.,  264.],
    [ -35.,  -79.,   52.,   96.],
    [ -79., -167.,   96.,  184.],
    [-167., -343.,  184.,  360.]]
```

The scale and aspect_ratios in faster rcnn paper is:

```
scale=[8, 16, 32]  
aspect_ratios=[0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
```

The scale and aspect_ratios in Google Object Detection API is:

```
scale=[0.5, 1.0, 2.0]   
aspect_ratio=[0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
```

Comment: did you figure out?